# JavaScript: Generating Random Numbers Within a Range

Tags: javascript

I started learning JS and I was watching a video about generating random numbers within a range.

This is a first method that I found:

```
function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {

   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (myMax - myMin + 1)) + myMin;
}
console.log(randomRange(10, 20));
```

And this is a second method I found:

```
function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 10;
}
console.log(randomRange());
```

So I'm interested if any of this two methods is better than other or something? I find second method a lot easier to understand. It generates the random number between 10 and 20 so 10 is the start and plus 11 is finish. Cheers!

Comment: First gives you more flexibility, the second is strange, it receives arguments but do not uses they and also hard-coded the range.

Comment: It is the same code...... One is hardcoded at 10, one is adjustable....

Comment: If mymin and mymax are 10 and 20 then mymax - mymin + 1 is 11 and my min is... 10.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Difference is,

In the first function, you pass arguments into myMin, myMax which allows you to generate random numbers based on the arguments.

```
function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {

   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (myMax - myMin + 1)) + myMin;
}
console.log(randomRange(10, 20));
```

Second function, you have formal parameters but they're not really used in the function since the range is static/hard-coded (11 & 10).

```
// You can just do function randomRange() {} without the formal parameters.
function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 10;
}
console.log(randomRange());
```

Conclusion, the first function is superior to the second function just because of the fact that it allows you to generate random numbers given the range you specify.

Comment: You're very welcome! Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are doing the same thing, except the second method is just hard coding the parameters to myMin=10 and myMax=20. So the first method can be used for different ranges, but the second method will always return random numbers in the range 10 to 20.

If you replace myMin and myMax in the first version with 10 and 20, you can simplify it to the second version:

`return Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 10 + 1)) + 10;`

`return Math.floor(Math.random() * (11) + 10;`

Comment: Ohh I get it! Thank you for taking time and answering!